# How to edit/fix a theme to make it support a newer version of gnome?

Tags: gnome, theme

**What I have:**

1. gnome 3.12
2. the Faence theme, http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/GTK3-Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456

**Current issue:**

The faence theme "only" supports gnome 3.10, I don't want to downgrade to gnome 3.10. As can be seen in the below image, the buttons on gtk popup windows and the buttons in nautilus are not rendering correctly: [image: http://i.imgur.com/VjAIWuW.png]

**What I want to do:**

I do not want to downgrade to gnome 3.10. I just want to edit this theme but the task seems daunting. I know that it is stored in `~/.themes` but tracking this bug down does not seem very productive. Does anyone have any idea where *start* looking in order to edit/fix these render issues on the buttons?